# ArrayList.Add GridView column value

Tags: c#, arraylist, gridview, indexoutofrangeexception

I have a little problem to get a `GridView`'s value and to add it into my `ArrayList`.

This is my code:

```
ArrayList tmp_array= new ArrayList();

for (int i = 1; i <= gridlist.Items.Count; i++)
{
    int num_id_actual=Convert.ToInt32( ((gridlist.Columns[0].GetCellContent(gridlist.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text.ToString()));
    num_id_actual= num_id_actual- 1;
    tmp_array.Add(num_id_actual.ToString());
}
```

The program crashes with error:

> Argument out of range exception was unhandled

Comment: have you tried with for loop starting from 0 to one less than gridlist.Items.Count. i.e. `for(int i = 0; i < gridlist.Items.Count;i++)`

Comment: When you get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` thrown, the first thing you should do is determine what the index is and what the valid range is. If you don't have that information then it's too soon to be posting here.

Comment: I also tried i = 0 but the result does not change

Comment: How many items gridlist.Items.Count is returning ? Are you sure all these items are inside the gridlist.Columns[0].GetCellContent ?

Comment: I tried to display all the values I'm using and I get correct results I think that error is only in Array.add because if instead of array use String it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

> I solved.

The problem is in the function `for (i >= grids.Items.Count){}` that does not take the value in the for function. you have to implement an

```
int size = grids.Items.Count;
for (int i = 0; i <= size; i ++)
{
// if I do this it works I do not know why but it's a solution
}
```